How to use superscript in ggplot2 title using a vector
I want to make a ggplot title with a superscript using a vector. A simple example would be like this:
df <- data.frame(x= rnorm(100)); df$y <- df$x**2

plot_title <- "Formula: y= x^2"
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title= plot_title)

I found this but the answers provided there do not work using a vector. I want the title to be:
Formula: y= x2

For those wondering why I do not use labs(title = bquote("Formula: y="~x^2)) or labs(title= expression(paste("Formula: y= ", x^2))), as suggested in the linked site: My actual use case is much more complex than the dummy data above. In my actual situation titles differ a lot, titles can be Formula: z= 2*s or something completely different. Therefore, I want to provide the titles with a string. So far I can not figure out how to.

The linked question should work here. In your case you can do plot_title <- "Formula: $y= x^2$" and labs(title= latex2exp::TeX(plot_title))

@SamR It woooorks! Thanks!
